# Jenkins SCM get parameter for validation

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to write a Jenkins SCM plugin.

[image: Screenshot of SCM plugin]

I need to validate the parameters (Test1, Test2).

Test1 depends upon DIR field.

Test2 depends upon DIR and Test1 fields.

Class containing Test1 & Test2 is a repeatable property. Config.jelly is following `

```
<f:entry title="DIR" field="Dir">
    <f:textbox />
</f:entry>

<f:entry title="Variable" field="var">
    <f:textbox />
</f:entry>

<f:entry>
    <f:repeatableProperty field="directories" noAddButton="true" minimum="1"/>
</f:entry>
```

`

and Config.jelly for directories is following

```
<j:jelly xmlns:j="jelly:core" xmlns:st="jelly:stapler" xmlns:d="jelly:define" xmlns:l="/lib/layout" xmlns:t="/lib/hudson" xmlns:f="/lib/form">
    <f:entry title="Test1" field="test1">
      <f:textbox />
    </f:entry>

    <f:entry title="Test2" field="test2">
      <f:textbox />
    </f:entry>

    <f:entry>
        <div align="right">
        <input type="button" value="${%Add more workareas}..." class="repeatable-add show-if-last"/>
        <input type="button" value="${%Delete}" class="repeatable-delete show-if-not-only" style="margin-left: 1em;"/>
    </div>
```

How can i get value of DIR field for validating Test1? I used 
`public FormValidation doCheckTest1(@QueryParameter String value, @QueryParameter String Dir)`

but i am getting Dir as null.

Comment: I am able to get the value of dir using @RelativePath("..")

Answer (score 0):

I am able to get the value of dir using @RelativePath("..")